# AWS Aurora High Availability High Level Diagram

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, alwayson, amazon-aurora

I am trying to find high level system documentation how AWS Aurora High Availability works. Below is a diagram on how MSSQL AlwaysOn works. Our company is thinking of migrating from MSSQL to Amazon AuroraDB. Does Amazon AWS have high level system documentation on how their system process works? Currently trying to review their system documentation.

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you google around they’ve done numerous blog posts and white papers on different facets of Aurora. Here’s one that seems to meet your needs from Werner Vogel’s blog

https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/p1041-verbitski.pdf

[image]

Comment: The first diagram quoted in the answer is not for Aurora, its for classic RDS Mysql. Aurora uses a distributed storage for data retention and not EBS.

Comment: The asker added in those diagrams.